# If a date range covers a whole specific month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a basic table:

```
ID  datefrom   dateto
555 09-AUG-16  19-AUG-16
400 16-MAY-16  04-OCT-16
555 04-APR-16  29-JUL-16
```

And i want to pick a specific month (year doesn't matter) say month 6.

And for that i would like to have the following output when the month = 6:

```
ID  datefrom   dateto    fullmonth
555 09-AUG-16  19-AUG-16 0
400 16-MAY-16  04-OCT-16 1
555 04-APR-16  29-JUL-16 1
```

They will get a value of 1 as the range contains the full month of June (6).

Comment: logic is still not clear though

Comment: @Rahul ive added a bit more.

Comment: Your `datefrom` and `dateto` appear to be varchar.  If so, don't do that!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen cant change data types, database is not editable.

Comment: Say you have dateFrom = 15/01/2016 and dateTo = 16/01/2017? Should January be considered contained or not?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? Find an algorithm? Or do you have an algorithm and don't know how to convert it into SQL? Or do you have SQL and have issues with it? Or haven't you done anything yourself yet?

Comment: @Aleksej no because its just 1 day of january, not the whole month. and it would only be considered if i was looking for january

Comment: The year doesn't matter? You want to get all ranges containing the full month no matter what year?

Comment: Its part of a larger query that is yearly based

Comment: What does yearly based mean? You only select data from one year, i.e. all dateto and datefrom in the same year?

Comment: And again: What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: doesnt matter, solved it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `datefrom` and `dateto` have the `DATE` datatype (otherwise use `TO_DATE()`) then, passing and date value within the month as the `chosen_month` bind parameter, you can use:

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN datefrom <= TRUNC( :chosen_month, 'MM' )
            AND  dateto   >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( :chosen_month, 'MM' ), 1 )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS fullmonth
FROM   table_name t
```

Or, passing a given year and month as numbers, then:

```
WITH chosen_date ( dt ) AS (
  SELECT TO_DATE(
           TO_CHAR( :chosen_year, '0000' )
           || TO_CHAR( :chosen_month, '00' )
           || '01',
           'YYYYMMDD'
         )
  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN datefrom <= c.dt
            AND  dateto   >= ADD_MONTHS( c.dt, 1 )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS fullmonth
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       chosen_date c
```

Or, if you want to consider it for the row's year then

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN datefrom <= month_start
            AND  dateto   >= ADD_MONTHS( month_start, 1 )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS fullmonth
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( datefrom, 'Y' ), :chosen_month - 1 ) AS month_start
  FROM   table_name t
) t
```

*Note: If you consider `from=2016-02-01, to=2016-02-29` to cover the whole month then replace the `ADD_MONTHS` function with `LAST_DAY`.*

Comment: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Comment: for chose month i want to put in either a single or double digit number e.g. 6 or 12 etc

Comment: `6` can be the index of a month with a year but `6` is not a month on its own. If you want to specify a month then you will need to give a month and a year (or, as I used, a date within that month). Otherwise, change the requirements to say you want it to be the full month in **any** year - which is an entirely different question.

Comment: I did "(year doesn't matter) "

Comment: @Matt Added some other options

Answer (score 0):

I used the `TO_DATE` function to generate a month (which will be parameterised when dropped into an Excel file via ODBC), along with using the `LAST_DAY` function in a `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT ID, datefrom, dateto,
CASE WHEN datefrom <= TO_DATE('6/2016', 'MM/YYYY')
            AND  dateto   >= LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('6/2016', 'MM/YYYY'))
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS fullmonth
FROM mytable
```

Output:

```
ID  datefrom   dateto    fullmonth
555 09-AUG-16  19-AUG-16 0
400 16-MAY-16  04-OCT-16 1
555 04-APR-16  29-JUL-16 1
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of part of my answer.

Comment: feel free to copy and paste my answer into yours and ill delete this one :)